# What do when you run out of water?

Tags: simcity-2013

In SimCity, it is possible to run out of water after you have pumped from an area for a long time.

What options do you have to remedy this?  Is the only hope buying water from other cities in the region?

What happens if all of the cities in the region run out of water?  Does it slowly regenerate or does this mean every region/city is bound to eventually run out of water?